# Is the union of an infinite sequence of finite sets an infinite set?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Given the following question:

"Let $X$ be an infinite set and define $\mu^*$ on $\mathcal P \left({X}\right)$ by $\mu^*(A) = 0$ if A is finite and $\mu^*(A)=1$ if A is infinite. Is $\mu^*$ an outer measure?"

If the union of an infinite sequence of finite subsets of X would be infinite then $\mu^*$ would not be countably subadditive, correct? Can anybody tell me if the union of an infinite sequence of finite subsets results in an infinite or a finite set?

Comment: Hint: Suppose your sets are $A_i={i}$ where $X= \mathbb{N}$, then what's their union?

Comment: You copied the question wrong. Read closely the two conditions on when $\mu^*(A)$ is $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Ok then the union is equal to $\mathbb{N}$, so its an infinite set.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks, I edited the question.

Comment: Isn't it more important that the subsets contribute inifinite many different elements in the end, than them being finite or infinite?

Comment: @YonedaLemma Not true. If all the sets are equal to $\{1\}$, then their union is finite.

Comment: @Vanio Please do not retag with [tag:set-theory]. As the description of the tag clearly indicates, this question does not fit there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An union of an infinite sequence of finite subsets can be either finite or infinite. If $A_i=\emptyset$ for every $i$, then $$\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i = \emptyset$$ is a finite set, but if $A_i=\{i\}$ for every $i\in\mathbb N$, then $$\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i=\mathbb N$$
which is an infinite set.

Comment: That is what I thought.

Comment: Thanks. If the sequence does not involve any empty sets, can you say that the union of these finite sets in that sequence is always infinite?

Comment: The finite sets could all be equal to each other. If you insist that they are pairwise unequal, then you may get what you want.

Comment: @eager2learn See comment by ned for your answer. Also, I see you posted your question $9$ minutes after I gave the original answer. I think you should spend more time thinking about the answer yourself, not just ask questions, as it will do much more good for your mathematical thinking.